# Apache Tomcat did not generate "catalina.out" and "localhost_access_log" files and deleting and running startup script in Linux EC2 instance

Tags: linux, tomcat, amazon-ec2

***tldr;** After deleting files in the logs folder and restarting the Apache service, "catalina.out" and "localhost_access_log" failed to generate*.

I am maintaining multiple instances that are running similar kind of services for different companies. We use **Apache Tomcat 7** to host a **Java application**, to maintain the log that are generated I run a **cronjob** every weekend to cleanup the **logs of pm2 and Tomcat**.

```
#!/bin/bash
    
#1. clear pm2 logs

 # stopping pm2 instance
pm2 stop 0

 #clearing logs
cd /home/ubuntu/.pm2
rm logs/*
> pm2.log

 #start the pm2 instance
pm2 start 0

#2. clear apache-tomcat logs

 #stop the apache-tomcat server
sudo sh  /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/bin/shutdown.sh

 #clear the cache
sudo rm /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/logs/*

 # start the apache-tomcat server
sudo sh /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/bin/startup.sh
```

On the previous Sunday(19/03/2022 00:00) my script ran for the first time, I updated 6 server with the cleanup script in which 3 had problem with starting the tomcat server. *I was able to see a pattern in the Tomcat's log folder, the servers that had problem with starting up had no "catalina.out" and "localhost_access_log" in them.*

```
Checked for logs in "/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/logs"
     
server 1 - crashed
    turbo.log  turbo.log-20.log
    
server 2 - crashed
    turbo.log  turbo.log-20.log
        
server 3
    catalina.out  turbo.log
    localhost_access_log.2022-03-19.txt  turbo.log-19.log
    localhost_access_log.2022-03-20.txt  turbo.log-20.log
    localhost_access_log.2022-03-21.txt


server 4
    catalina.out  turbo.log
    localhost_access_log.2022-03-19.txt  turbo.log-19.log
    localhost_access_log.2022-03-20.txt  turbo.log-20.log
    localhost_access_log.2022-03-21.txt

server 5
    catalina.out  turbo.log
    localhost_access_log.2022-03-19.txt  turbo.log-19.log
    localhost_access_log.2022-03-20.txt  turbo.log-20.log
    localhost_access_log.2022-03-21.txt

server 6 - crashed
    turbo.log  turbo.log-19.log  turbo.log-20.log
```

**I would like know what could have gone wrong with the 3 servers , and what should I need to update in the script to make sure the **"catalina.out" and "localhost_access_log"** are always generated.**

Comment: Note that Apache httpd ([tag:apache]) != Apache Tomcat. Also, Tomcat 7 had its [EOL](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-70-eol.html) almost exactly 1 year ago and the version that you seem to be running has been published in 2014. And if you run tomcat as root, as `sudo` makes me suspect, then you certainly have different problems than a logfile not being generated.

Comment: Thanks Olaf Kock for helping. I am interested in knowing more about the problem, could please explain me the same or even sharing a blog or a video for the same will be very helpful.

Comment: Which problem? Running horribly outdated software on a server connected to the internet? Running a server exposed to the internet as root? Should be fairly obvious: You're missing 8 years of security updates, and if one of the well known security issues is exploited, the attacker has _full root access_ on your system immediately.

Comment: Thank you Olaf Kock for explaining the problem. I was not aware of the consequence before, now that I have know I will be carful with it.